# webstorm doesn't stop on breakpoints in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I'm trying to use debugger in webstorm 8.
I created an express application and set breakpoint in index.js file. When I start application in debug mode, I see the message in console:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=2610 --nolazy bin\www
debugger listening on port 2610

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

But in simple mode application works normally. It also works if I run it in debug mode, but without any breakpoints.

Here is a picture of my config. There is also a breakpoint at line 6 and error log.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/axqwazz30m89o4r/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-10-19%2003.44.53.png?dl=0

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your project directory has some char not in english , have you try change it in a english directory ?